# one to many and one to one relation with RequireJS and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have two amd modules with two models `User` and `File`. `User` has many `files` and `File` has one `User`.

```js
define('model/user', ['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    return Backbone.Model.exend({
        getFiles: function () {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

and

```js
define('model/file', ['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    return Backbone.Model.exend({
        getUser: function () {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

All entities already created in controllers.

```js
define('controller/users', ['backbone', 'model/user'], function (Backbone, User) {
    var users = new Backbone.Collection([], {
        model: User
    });
    users.fetch();
});
```

and

```js
define('controller/files', ['backbone', 'model/file'], function (Backbone, File) {
    var files = new Backbone.Collection([], {
        model: File
    });
    files.fetch();
});
```

I can't figure out how to make these cross-relationships (methods `getFiles` and `getUser`)?

I can't make `model/user` require `model/file` which will require `model/user`. Models can't require controllers. Maybe there should be third module `store` with all created models in it? Then how they should get there?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using backbone on the front end you could easily get away with not defining the relation in the model layer, but instead - having them in the controller layer.
Coupling related models together is not necessarily the best pattern.

However, if you want the relations to be a part of the model layer, I would look into libraries such as http://backbonerelational.org/